# MS Graph SDK search in message subject returns error

Tags: c#, graph

I'm using MS Graph SDK in my C# code to find an e-mail at Exhange Server mailbox by mail subject. For searching I use QueryOptions. The code looks:

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{ 
    new QueryOption("$filter", "startswith(Subject,'" + message.Subject + "')")
};
IUserMessagesCollectionPage messages = graphClient.Users[user.Id].Messages.Request(options).Top(200).GetAsync().Result;
```

When the mail subject contains **#** character the function returns error: "Invalid filter clause". When the subject contains only letters or numbers everything is OK and message collection is returned.
I don't how to solve it. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HttpUtility.UrlEncode solved the problem.

```
 new QueryOption("$filter", "startswith(Subject,'" +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message.Subject) + "')")
```

Comment: If i could, i would have given you 10 upvotes for your answer. Thank you so much, was very frustrating until now.